# "Failed to subscribe" - poclbm over SSL - Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, poclbm

So I have setup `bitcoind -daemon` on a server. On plain HTTP, I can connect to the server from my machine and start mining with `poclbm.py` (at a slow rate but I am preparing my environment before upgrading H/W)

Then I have created the self-signed certificate successfully, and from a remote machine I can get the SSL certificate validation using `openssl s_client` command. I had trouble with the `openssl s_client` command when not including the

```
rpcsslciphers=TLSv1+HIGH:!SSLv2:!aNULL:!eNULL:!AH:!3DES:@STRENGTH
```

part in the conf, but after adding it it as ok.

Then added option `rpcssl=1` in bitcoin.conf.

Now I get a `Failure to subscribe` followed by `IO errors - 1, tolerance 2`.

Is there anything else to check? Running `poclbm` with `-verbose` doesn't show more output.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the (quite old) source code of poclbm, there is a commented line that creates the SSL connection. Not sure it is the reason but I guess it doesn't support HTTPS in its last version.
I changed to DiabloMiner (I had to add my self-signed certificate using the [InstallCert.java](http://code.google.com/p/java-use-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/com/aw/ad/util/InstallCert.java) tool)

I can now mine over HTTPS. Next step is a pool...